Creating Pandas Series from Dictionary
I'm going through the Python Data Science Handbook to learn about the Pandas library. The book says, and also shows an example, that when a Series is created from a dictionary, the index defaults to the sorted dictionary keys. When I try the same example or even a different example in Jupyter Notebook, I see that the index is not sorted. Am I missing something here?
data = pd.Series({2: 'a', 1: 'b', 3: 'c'})

2    a
1    b
3    c
dtype: object

Here's the example from the book:


Most probably that's from a book referencing older versions of Pandas. I think that's not  longer the default behavior
